# Logical question with map<set,vectors>?

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, set

I've a map `map<set,vector> m1`. It has values as follows:

```
< <1>,<2,4> >
< <2>,<6,2> >
< <3>,<3,4> >
< <4>,<6,1> >
< <5>,<1,1> >
```

Now I have to find the maximum values in each column of the vector and I do that easily by iterating all the rows and I store it in a vector say `v1` as `<6,4>`.

Now the problem is I want to find all the pairs that constitute to this value. Think of it like what are all the possible combination that can produce `<6,4>` in the map. i.e. my result should also be a map that looks something like this :

```
< <1,2>,<6,4> >
< <2,3>,<6,4> >
< <1,4>,<6,4> >
< <3,4>,<6,4> >
```

> EDIT:

To explain more, let the set in the map act as an `id` of the corresponding vector. Now, what are all the vectors in that map "combined" can produce a <6,4> ?  Note that the aggregate function here is the `max`. i.e given to vectors `<2,4>` and `<6,2>`, the max between them is `<6,4>` so id's (1 and 2) and (2 and 3) and so on can give me <6,4>.

What I was trying to do is iterate through every column of the vector in m1 and store the corresponding `set` values whenever I find a `6`, in this example `< <2> <6,2> >` and `< <4>,<6,1> >` and do the same for the second column. Now I do not know how to integrate it to get my result.

Comment: I use the sets as just ID's and since there is a value 4 in id 1 and 6 in id 2. I want to show that id's 1,2 can produce the max value in `v1`.

Comment: I just read this four times, very slowly. I then looked at both answers which exist right now. I still don't understand the problem. In `< <1>, <2,4> >`, the `<1>` part is your std::set with one element, and the `<2,4>` part is your std::vector with two elements? What do you mean with `maximum values in each column of the vector` - a vector is one dimensional, why the row/column wording?

Comment: Given a vector v1 having <6,4> I want to find all the values in the map<set,vectors> that has a 6 in the first element and 4 in the second element of the vector in the map. Think of it like a 8 queens problem. First I find the value in the map that has a 6 and then I search the values second element that has a 4 and give as output. Once I've no more 4's I cbacktrack and find next 6 and do the same and so on..

Comment: @Frerich : Could you get my idea ?

Comment: @Sunil: I thought I understood what you meant but then I saw that xjdrew implemented the exact same algorithm you described - but you didn't accept this. So I must be missing something. For each vector in the given map, check whether the vector starts with `v1` (that is, first element is 6, second is 4). If so, memorize that map element by storing an iterator somewhere.

Comment: @Frerich : Yes, for each vector in the map I will check if the first element is equal to the first element in the vector `v1`. If so, I'll proceed and check from the start of the map if the second element of ANY vector is equal to the second element in `v1. If I find one I print out the combinations that produced it else backtrack and check the next element in the first "dimension" of the vectors that is equal to 6 and so on and so forth.

Comment: Maintaining the indexes is the tedious problem and I'm not familiar with recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SI map<set,vector>::iterator

mx = find_max();
vector<set> ret;
for(SI it=m1.begin();it!=m1.end();it++){
  for(SI it2=it;it2=m1.end();it++){
     if(it==it2)continue;//nasty
     if(find_max2(it,it2)==mx)
        ret.push_back(it->first,it2->first);
  }
}
```

I don't know if this have compilation errors, but you can get the point.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SI map<set,vector>::iterator

vector<SI> ret;
for(SI it=m1.begin();it!=m1.end();it++){
    if(equal(v1.begin(),v1.end(),it->second.begin()){
        ret.push_back(it);
    }
}
```

use std::equal to compare two vector.

Comment: This doesn't give my answer. This just compares two vectors. This just finds if there is a vector with value `<6,4>` but that's not what I want.

Comment: you can modify ret value type to map<set,vector> and changes ret.push_back(it) to ret[*it] = it->second.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit? Thanks

Comment: Please, replace that ugly `#define` with a `typedef`.